# Restrict outgoing email from some subdomain to internal domains only using postfix

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I am new to email servers and after some time and hard work I managed to configure a mail server, all the certs, all the ports etc... Everything is working really fine! And now I was requested to create an internal subdomain so that the email accounts from this subdomain can only send an receive internal email.

Just let me clarify:

`john@example.com` can send and receive emails from/to anybody, including Gmail or Outlook accounts.

`mary@sales.example.com` can send and receive emails from/to anybody, including Gmail and Outlook accounts.

`peter@press.example.com` can send and receive emails from/to anybody, including Outlook and Gmail accounts.

*BUT!*

`thomas@internal.example.com` can only send and receive emails from/to `john@example.com`, `mary@sales.example.com`, `peter@marketing.example.com` or even `ralph@internal.example.com` or whatever from the same domain/subdomain. But someone with an `@internal.example.com` account **should not** be able to send or receive emails from GMail, Outlook or `@company.com`.

I found the way to create Sieve Filters to automatically discard external emails sent TO internal accounts but now I need to block any email sent FROM `@internal.example.com` accounts to external email address.

I am using Postfix as MTA and I think this can be achieved with it but, as I said, I am new to email servers. I did my research and couldn't success. So, I guess is time to ask for some help and I hope you can help me on that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [header_checks](http://www.postfix.org/header%5Fchecks.5.html) to achieve it, may be necessary to include some if statement on it.